# pysvn obtaining file mode (symlink, executable, file, or dir) from http request

Tags: python, file, executable, symlink, pysvn

I am trying to create a database storing all information with given repository url.

By using pysvn API, I am trying to obtain file mode (symlink, executable, file) from just by http request.

I tried using list and info2 method where it returns information regards to my http url. Both method has an attribute 'kind' in the returned dictionary, but 'kind' only determines if it is a 'file' or 'dir'.

I read the docs on http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html but couldn't find anything that can find the file mode without saving the file to local disk.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that to get filemode you need to first check if file has property. Method list() has attribute to has_prop.

http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_list

If there is property, use method proplist() to get a list of tuple containing path and prop_dict where prop_dict can determine the filemode for given files.

http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_proplist